# Which language is supported in the [code] section of Inno-Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to learn to write custom code in Inno-Setup installers using the [code] section.

I want to know which programming language is used for that purpose and if there's a book or books I can read to know the language syntax, learn typical usage and see practical examples.

Comment: I believe that it uses Pascal

Comment: @voters to close.  This is a very simple and concrete question.  There's only one category that I can possibly imagine this getting closed under and that category is **Exact Duplicate** if this question already exists somewhere

Comment: and I suspect the reason why this question has close votes is because it reads like a shopping question.  For future reference, You should know that asking for books examples and resources attracts negative attention here.

Comment: @SamIam, once again, it's not Pascal, it's Pascal Script. About close votes. Have you read FAQ and seen [`How to learn`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn&submit=search) questions ?

Comment: @TLama  have you read the question?  it was `"Which language is supported in the [code] section of Inno-Setup?"` It's a very simple, very concrete question: **What language does Inno-Setup use?**, and the amount of googling required is such that It's perfectly believable that someone could spend 5-10 minutes looking and still not find it.  Yes, there is some un-necessary fluff that reads like a shopping question or a "how to learn question", but behind it all is a very simple and concrete question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inno Setup's `[Code]` section uses [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29) (or [Pascal Script](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) to be more exact, thanks to TLama), likely because Inno Setup itself is written in Pascal Delphi.

For books on pascal, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1665458/492336

Comment: No, it doesn't use Pascal! It's [`Pascal Script`](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) what is something different! This answer is just wrong [haven't voted down if someone].

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer. However, wouldn't Pascal Script still be Pascal the language, i.e. same syntax, etc. From his point of view, does code written for Pascal differ from code written for Pascal Script? I mean, java can be compiled or ran in a VM, but it's still the same language.

Comment: No it's not the same language! Yeah, syntax is similar, but differs in few points (you can't declare certain types, cannot use custom classes and there's many other minor, but important differences, whose from time to time limit InnoSetup script developers).